# Find an estimator for the probability of a given random variable

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> Let $X$ be a random variable with a Binomial distribution $X \sim B(100,p)$. We want to find the probability $P\{X<4\}$ by estimating the parameter $p$ using the method of moments and maximum likelihood method.

I'm stuck. All I could do was conclude that using the method of moments, an estimator for $p$ would be $\bar X/100$. What am I supposed to do with this information and how can I use the ML method for the binomial distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by $\bar X$?  Usually that denotes a sample mean, but in this case your sample seems to consist only of a single oberservation $X$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I changed $X$ ~ $B(100,p)$ to $X\sim B(100,p)$ and $P${$X<4$} to $P\{X<4\}$.  Putting "$\sim$" and the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ INSIDE of MathJax is standard usage and makes the fonts and alignment and spacing match. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you, I noted the change. Also, isn't that how the method of moments works? If I understood correctly, I am supposed to equate $\mathbb E[X]$ ,which is 100*p, with the sample mean $\bar X$.

Comment: Since you have only one observation, $X$, I wondered about your introduction of a separate notation, $\bar X$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Isn't $n=100$ ?

Comment: But what you would do would be $\sum P(1<X<4)={n\choose k}p^kq^{n-k}+...$, replacing $k \in [1,3], n=100, p=\bar{X}/100$

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I understand correctly. So far I've only been using these two methods to estimate parameters by themselves, but the whole $P\{X<4\}$ thing got me confused.

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze : Where do you get $1<X<4$?  That would mean $X=2\text{ or }3$.  But $X<4$ is the same as $X=0,1,2,\text{ or } 3$.  And what do you mean by $\sum P(1<X<4)$?  ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the sample size is $1$.  The first sample moment is the mean of the observations in the sample, and since there is only one such observation, it is just the value of that observation, $X$.  The first population moment for $B(100,p)$ is $100p$.  In the method of moments one then equates the two and solves for $p$, thus:
$$
X=100p
$$
$$
p = \frac X {100}.
$$
That is the estimate of $p$ by the method of moments.  The likelihood function is
$$
L(p) = \binom {100} X p^X (1-p)^{100-X}.
$$
Finding the value of $p$ that maximizes this is the same as finding the value of $p$ that maximizes its logarithm because the logarithm function is increasing.  The logarithm is
$$
\ell(p) = \log\binom{100} X + \left( X\log p + (100-X)\log(1-p) \right).
$$
Then we have
$$
\ell\,'(p) = \frac X p - \frac{100-X}{1-p} = \frac{-100\left( p - \dfrac X {100} \right)}{p(1-p)} \quad \begin{cases} \ge 0 & \text{if }0<p\le 100/X, \\[8pt]  \le 0 & \text{if }100/X \le p < 1. \end{cases}
$$
Hence the maximizing value of $p$ is $\dfrac X {100}$.

Both methods yield the same estimate in this case.

If you use that estimate in place of $p$ in $\Pr(X<4)$ then you get
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X\in\{0,1,2,3\}) \\[10pt]
= {} & \binom {100} 0 \hat p^0(1-\hat p)^{100} + \binom{100} 1 \hat p^1(1-\hat p)^{99} + \binom{100} 2 p^2 (1-\hat p)^{98} + \binom{100} 3 \hat p^3(1-\hat p)^{97}
\end{align}
where $\hat p = X/100$ is the estimate.